# Missing .env in Vue CLI after run build

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, production-environment, vue-cli-3

I'm building an app using Vue CLI 3. 
I've included `.env` in my project and everything works fine.

But when i'm building the app for production via `npm run build` there is no `.env` file in my `dist` folder, so i can't change my environmental variables in production server.
Any solution or it's just fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is supposed to happen. The env variables are embedded in your build.

You can make seperate .env files for production. These variables will be used during the production build.

Create a new .env file named: `.env.production`

Source: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes

Answer (score 2):

It is normal because application needed to be recompiled when `.env` file changed.

For convenience you can use `.env.prod` or `.env.dev` for your CI/CD pipeline.